# Appium Test on Appium server hosted on a VPS

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to create a simple Android app which can connect to Appium Server hosted on a VPS and do the automation on an Android emulator or a real device when the app is launched.
I am getting the following error in Android Studio even the same Appium server is accessible from another Python script:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
                                                                                                    Host info: host: 'Unknown', ip: 'Unknown'
```

Here is the function to run when a button is clicked:

```
private void initAppiumDriver() {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");

        try {
            URL appiumServerURL = new URL("vps_url/wd/hub");
            driver = new AndroidDriver(appiumServerURL, capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

vps_url is placeholder here. The actual URL is accessible from browser and another Python script.